# How to manage SQL Result wordpress

Tags: php, sql, json, wordpress

I am writing a PHP statement for an ios app to get results from the Post_meta field in Wordpress.
We use a plugin for woocommerce to see where the article is stored.

I wrote the code but in the wordpress database the meta_value is stored in an odd way:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:9:{s:5:"title";s:22:"Brands Meubeltransport";s:6:"plaats";s:7:"Tegelen";s:8:"postcode"; s:7:"5932 AA";s:5:"adres";s:17:"Tichlouwstraat 45";s:5:"email"; s:33:"k.brands@brandsmeubeltransport.nl";s:8:"telefoon";s:11:"077-3738245"; s:4:"site";s:22:"http://www.linteloo.nl";s:2:"id";s:26:"tab-brands-meubeltransport";s:7:"content";s:0:"";}}
```

How can i transform this adres information into a redable string or how can i use this string in Xcode to retrieve adress and postalcode?

Comment: The "odd way" is JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `unserialize ( string $str )` the string , worpress stores the information as [**serialized**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) string if array of values is passed

[**unserialize ( string $str )**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

```
$result=unserialize( $meta_value ); /* get string fro db and unserialize it  */
print_r($result);
/* to see what is in the array and what you need to grab
like echo  $result['adres']; echo  $result['title'];
*/
```